# Flutter TextFormField not unfocus previous one

Tags: flutter

Good day for everybody. I have a problem with flutter textformfield. When I pass to next textformfield it not unfocus previous one. It's happen when tap next field too. I tried my app on real phone (G3 and Mi 9t) and its happen both of them. I can't found solution in net. I add image below. Image show problem more clear. Thanks for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpwTV.jpg)

Code for Form:

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        focusNode: _emailFocus,
        onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
          _emailFocus.unfocus();

          _fieldFocusChange(
              context, _emailFocus, _passwordFocus);
        },
        validator: (value) =>
        value.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() => email = value);
        },
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        validator: (value) => value.length < 6
            ? 'Enter an password 6+ chars long'
            : null,
        obscureText: true,
        focusNode: _passwordFocus,
        onFieldSubmitted: (term) async {
          _passwordFocus.unfocus();

          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            setState(() => loading = true);
            dynamic result = await _authService
                .registration(email, password);
            if (result == null) {
              setState(() {
                error = "please supply a valid email";
                loading = false;
              });
            }
          }
        },
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() => password = value);
        },
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Text('Register'),
        onPressed: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            setState(() => loading = true);
            dynamic result = await _authService
                .registration(email, password);
            if (result == null) {
              setState(() {
                error = "please supply a valid email";
                loading = false;
              });
            }
          }
        },
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 12.0),
      Text(error,
          style:
          TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0)),
    ],
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of unfocusing your current field, you want to focus the next field. Inside your submitted you need to call `requestFocus()` or `nextFocus()` ([documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html)) to move the focus to the following field, in your case the password field as I'm doing below:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  focusNode: _emailFocus,
  onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
    _passwordFocus.requestFocus();

    _fieldFocusChange(
        context, _emailFocus, _passwordFocus);
  },
  validator: (value) =>
  value.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() => email = value);
  },
),
```

I would also advise you to move the code you have on the Button to a method, so that you can re-use it on the Button and the Password field submit:

```
void submitForm(){
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() => loading = true);
    dynamic result = await _authService
        .registration(email, password);
    if (result == null) {
      setState(() {
        error = "please supply a valid email";
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer. By the way thanks for answer. It solve next button problem but when tap password field same problem.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the password field is filled in and submitted?

Comment: I'm using firebase and sent to user home page. Authentication and other system work. I need when user type email and password and make a mistake turn email field not show two input field have typestick (I don't know that thing name sorry).

Comment: I'm sorry, your last comment is a bit confusing. Can you simplify the problem. Just explain what you want to happen when the password field is submitted.

Comment: Thanks I think same thing. I will make.

Comment: Password field submit not have problem. Like you can see in my image I have two field focus. But actually you write text only in one field.

Comment: So when you are typing on the email field, the password field is getting written on as well?

Comment: No when I write email field and focus next field, write something (Let say password field typing) and return email field again it show two text typing bar (Or typing animation). Sorry about my bad explanation before.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. That is very odd indeed. I've never seen this issue before. But since I answered your original question, could you mark my answer as correct? And then you can ask a new question specifically about the cursor appearing in two fields at the same time.

Comment: Actually its my question from start :) . Are you know the answer for this problem? Sorry I new for this site but Can I change my title or need to create new question?

Comment: Your original question was about focus nodes between fields. Please mark my answer as correct and open a new one for the other question.

Comment: Thanks for answer I create now new one.